# remove position:relative property in media query

Tags: html, css

Hello I have a div in which i have applied the styling

```
position:relative;
```

here is my code

```
 #cssmenu ul li{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
    list-style: none;
    line-height: 1;
    display: block;
    position: relative;
}
```

in media query i don't want any position attribute `position:static;`

here is my media query code

```
    @media (max-width: 768px), only screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2) and (max-width: 1024px), not all, not all, not all, only screen and (max-width: 1024px) and (min-resolution: 192dpi), only screen and (max-width: 1024px) and (min-resolution: 2dppx)
#cssmenu, #cssmenu ul, #cssmenu ul li, #cssmenu ul li a, #cssmenu #menu-button {
    position: static !important;
}
```

this query is not helping me to achieve output .
how do i remove position property in media query

Answer (score 1):

There is a syntax error in media query section,whenever we define a media query we need to include the styles under parenthesis like:

```
  @media (max-width: 768px){
<our css style>
}
```

Working code:

```css
#cssmenu ul li{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
    list-style: none;
    line-height: 1;
    display: block;
    position: relative;
}
 @media (max-width: 768px),not all, only screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2) and (max-width: 1024px),screen and (max-width: 1024px) and (min-resolution: 192dpi), only screen and (max-width: 1024px) and (min-resolution: 2dppx){
#cssmenu, #cssmenu ul, #cssmenu ul li, #cssmenu ul li a, #cssmenu #menu-button {
    position: static !important;
}
}
```

```html
<div id='cssmenu'>
  <ul>
    <li>Ankit</li>
    <li>Ch</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
```